# Specular intensity of non-metals(plastics) in metalness pbs workflow

Tags: shaders, pbr

The specular color in metalness/roughness workflow is usually defined as following:

```
float3 specColor = lerp(0.03f, albedoColor, metallic);
```

The Cook-Torrance BRDF is given with the following formula:

[image: Cook-Torrance BRDF]

The final color will be:

```
Ci = (diffColor*(n.l)+Ks*specColor*cook);
```

My question is - won't specular be too dim for non-metals? Cook-Torrance term will be multiplied by 0.03 in case of dielectrics - this will make the specular component virtually non-existent. This doesn't seem realistic to me, because smooth plastic reflects a lot of light, almost as much as metals:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I think I got my answer - Beckmann distribution term from the Cook-Torrance equation becomes really high when the roughness is low:
For roughness = 0.01 the Beckmann term becomes 3183; for 0.001, it becomes 318310.

The roughness has to be much lower on non-metals to make the specular highlight noticeable.